# How to use Java class type in code

Tags: java

I've used and extended classes where the name looks like `ArrayAdapter<String>` or `HashMap<String, String>`, but how can implement the type inside the `<>` myself? For example, I have a class that is currently used to store callback data. It looks like:

```
static class APICallback {
    boolean status;
    JsonObject data;
}
```

Is there a way for me to implement this so that I can code something like `APICallback<List<String>>` and have it know the data field will be a `List<String>` vs a `JsonObject`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class would have to be a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

E.g:

```
static class APICallback<T> {
    boolean status;
    T data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to know about [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) (from the link) *a generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types*. One possible way to make your class generic would be

```
static class APICallback<T> {
    boolean status;
    JsonObject data;
    List<T> al;
}
```